# How to direct traffic of users of certain countries to the right server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, routes, traffic

The question rather concerns alternatives to Amazon Route 53 and Google Cloud DNS (Direct traffic). As far as I understand from the descriptions of these services, they only work together with their other services.

I'm trying to find a service that will allow you to determine the country of a user and, if necessary, redirect all of its traffic to the correct server.

For example, I have two servers - the main server with the application and the proxy server. By default, I want to direct all users directly to the main server. But users of certain countries I want to pass through the second - a proxy server.

Tell me, please, how best to implement all this. Perhaps you have any more correct options for implementation?

Comment: Why do you believe that geographic DNS lookups are limited to AWS (or Google) services? Do you have a reference to something that claims this?

Comment: @guest As I wrote above: "As far as I understand"... In the Google Cloud panel, I could not understand how to implement it. There was something about VM...

Comment: I can't speak about Google Cloud, but as far as AWS goes I can't see anything that would prevent you from doing it (I use Route53 to provide DNS resolution for non-Amazon servers, but haven't used geographic routing).

Comment: @guest Okay. I understood you. I will read again.

Comment: @guest This is it? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo

Comment: @guest Only now I was able to get to practice. I looked at Traffic policies. As I understand it (and did it) I can select a country and specify an end point for it. But Route 53 cannot mask the server IP. That is, I have to specify the server IP available for a particular country.